# how to restrict wgpu for only a section of the window?

Tags: rust

how do i set the viewport of a wgpu application to only use the center of the screen? I want to have triangles and the background color to only render in a given area, and the rest of the area outside of that box is using a seperate renderer, but after asking chatgpt and google without results i dont know what to do

Comment: can you share what have you tried so far https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example